# Ajax post submit form ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

Where actually I can get my variable pass to my js.erb, let say

I have 1 method create,in controller
in my application.js, i have my Ajax post
then I have my create.js.erb

In my create form, I have 2 hidden_field_tag
In my create.js.erb , this is here where the ajax success post and do the action, but how do I access the hidden_field data to carry out my logic to perform certain action when success?

This is due to, when it's js success, I got 2 different action to determine which action I should process.
How actually js.erb works? Besides, when I alert the form data in application.js, it dont come out the alert although the js is working perfectly. Any idea?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#new_answer").submit(function() {
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    alert("you are submitting" + $(this).serialize()); //it dint work but it did post
    return false;
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wait, when you do this, lets say your :controller => "months" and
>   :action => "march".

I mean your $(this).action() returns "/months/march".

> This will stored in url and when you hit that url by the below post method, the form elements are available in the "march" action of the "months" controller in the params hash.

Now, in the "result" js variable, the whole params hash will be available, which is actually you are alerting.

months_controller.rb

```
def march

  render :text => params

end
```

application.js

```
$("form#new_answer").submit(function() {  

          var data = $('form#new_answer').serialize();

          var url = $(this).action();

           $.post(url ,data, function(result){

            alert(result);

            });        

           return false;

          });
```

Comment: is this still process my script ?? eg: create.js.erb

Comment: i tested,it still process,but it dont alert the data ...i was wondering whats happening.

Comment: erm, yea..but when I tried to alert the params which is my hidden field tag in the form, no matter in the controller or js.erb , it shows me undefined or blank ...any idea?

Comment: beside , i do var data = $('#ele').val(); and alert(data) ,in my js.erb, it shows undefined..I tot it should be available?

Comment: can you post your controller and js.erb files?

Comment: ya ,such silly , its because of my hidden field tag matter , it should <%= hidden instead of <% ...thanks your afford.