# JQuery ajax to invoke method in controller and store the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have this code in JS:

```
  $("#send_button").click(function(){
    var isitArray = getObjectsRequest('isit', isitID);
    var ecArray = getObjectsRequest('ec', ecID);
    var bcArray = getObjectsRequest('bc', bcID);
    var bbArray = getObjectsRequest('bb', bbID);
    var ioArray = getObjectsRequest('io', ioID);

    function getObjectsRequest(type, compId){
      var array = [];
      for (var i = 0; i<compId; i++) {
        var comp = mainLayer.find('#'+ type + i)[0];
        array.push({
          xposition: comp.getX(),
          yposition: comp.getY(),
          titleid: comp.getId(),
          description: comp.find('.textDescription')[0].getText(),
          leftrelationsids: comp.leftCRelations,
          rightrelationsids: comp.rightCRelations
        });
      };
      return array;
    }

    var datatosend = {
        isit: isitArray,
        ec: ecArray,
        bc: bcArray,
        bb: bbArray,
        io: ioArray
    };

    var diagramName = $("#diagramName").val();
    if(diagramName==''){
      alert("Enter the diagram name!");
    } else {
      datatosend.diagramname = diagramName;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insertdata.php",
        data: datatosend,
        dataType: "text"
      })
      .done(function( msgReply ) {
        alert("Data saved with success.");
        //alert( "Data Saved: " + msgReply );
        displayDiagrams();
      });
    }

    return false;
  });
```

This ajax jquery example uses a php file. I'm integrating this tool into an application in ruby on rails. My objective is to store the diagram data using a method in Diagram controller.

Is it possible to store the data using this kind of ajax request? More like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/diagrams",
        data: datatosend,
        dataType: "html"
```

Invoking the create method in the Diagram controller.

How should I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405328/ajax-post-submit-form-ruby-on-rails

Comment: You should remove of the question the non-essential items (for example the code you use to build `datatosend`) to make clear what your problem is. On the other hand, you ask about "how should I do this?", you should comment on what did you try before (so we know you did some research).